# Connecting to Lastfm Api, can get all information except from the artist image

Tags: php

so I am connecting to the last fm API which the info looks like this

```
{"topartists":{"artist":[{"name":"Bee Gees","mbid":"bf0f7e29-dfe1-416c-b5c6-f9ebc19ea810","url":"https://www.last.fm/music/Bee+Gees","streamable":"0","image":[{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/1df682d5ba6e45db843c45a336170470.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/1df682d5ba6e45db843c45a336170470.png","size":"medium"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/1df682d5ba6e45db843c45a336170470.png","size":"large"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/1df682d5ba6e45db843c45a336170470.png","size":"extralarge"},{"#text":"https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/1df682d5ba6e45db843c45a336170470.png","size":"mega"}],"@attr":{"rank":"1"}}
```

In my php code i use

```
        class LastFm{

    private $api_key;
    const url = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/';

    function __construct($api_key){
        $this->api_key = $api_key;
    }

    function call($method,$params=array()){
        $lastfm = self::url.'?method='.$method.'&format=json&api_key='.$this->api_key;
        foreach($params as $key => $value){
            $lastfm .= '&'.$key.'='.urlencode($value);
        }
        $json = file_get_contents($lastfm);
        return json_decode($json, true);
    }

}

?>
<?php

$lastfm = new LastFm('63692beaaf8ba794a541bca291234cd3');




$tracks = $lastfm->call('tag.gettopartists&tag=disco');
foreach($tracks['topartists']['artist'] as $track){


?>
```

Which successfully returns the artist name. But how do I get the medium sized image? I've tried -

```
  `echo $artist['image'];`
```

but nothing gets returned.

Comment: looks like `image` is an array of objects, have you tried `$artist['image'][1]`? also what's the output of `dd($artist['image'])`?

Comment: @Ali means var_dump($track); within the foreach. `dd` is a Laravel function and not native php.

Comment: right on @admcfajn!

Comment: $artist['image'][1] doesn't show anything. Have already tried this one!

Comment: Var_dump shows

array(6) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Bee Gees" ["mbid"]=> string(36) "bf0f7e29-dfe1-416c-b5c6-f9ebc19ea810" ["url"]=> string(34) "https://www.last.fm/music/Bee+Gees" ["streamable"]=> string(1) "0" ["image"]=> array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { ["#text"]=> string(78) "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/1df682d5ba6e45db843c45a336170470.png" ["size"]=> string(5) "small" } [1]=> array(2) { ["#text"]=> string(78) "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/1df682d5ba6e45db843c45a336170470.png" ["size"]=> string(6) "medium" } [2]=> array(2) { ["#text"]=> string(79)

Comment: Thanks @Ali, lots of Laravel lately? ;) 
Jamie: instead of `return json_decode($json, true);`, test with this: `var_dump(json_decode($json, true));` and add the result to your question please. `$track->image[0]['#text']` or `$track['image'][0]['#text']` could be what you're looking for

Comment: @admcfajn I think we are getting closer - when I tried $track['image'][0]['#text']

It seems to print the image URL but for everything on http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=tag.gettopartists&tag=disco&api_key=63692beaaf8ba794a541bca291234cd3&format=json

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo '<img src="'.$track['image'][0]['#text'].'">';` is what you're looking for.

The `0` is the index within the `$track['image']` array, you may want to change that based on the image size you want... Or, you can loop it and populate a new array of images

```
$images = [];
foreach($track['image'] as $image){
    $images[] = [ $image['size']=>$image['#text'] ];
}

echo '<img src="'.$images['small'].'"/>;
```

Comment: Have just tried the above, however it is printing every artists image, not just the one image for that artist if it makes sense, its printing em all

Comment: Where are you placing that in your code? Can you paste your full-code to a pastebin and I'll take a look? It sounds like you've got a loop nested incorrectly.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Cd2jUEdi is the code

https://imgur.com/a/zSk3I . is a screenshot :)

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what it should, that foreach loop is looping over all of the items returned from the api (each of which is a track with an image). To get a single-artist, maybe try a different endpoint. Are you looking for a way to _only_ output one artist? I'm happy to help, but you've accepted an answer on one of your ten questions and I've already answered this one... So I'm wondering if moving forward with this is even worth my time.

Comment: Oh, It's working as it should - my bad! super sorry, thanks for your help mate

Comment: You've still got an echo at the beginning of your foreach. change `foreach($tracks['topartists']['artist'] as $track){echo $track['image'][0]['#text'];` to `foreach($tracks['topartists']['artist'] as $track){` :) also, if you delete those questions which are getting downvotes your profile-points will improve :) then maybe rephrase them and re-post, but be sure to search around lots first. Many questions you may want to ask already have ansers on here. All good Jamie, cheers! Didn't mean to be a ****, just spent many hours helping people on here and gotten burned a few times.

Comment: Really appreciate it, I will get on that! thanks for your help mate.